# Migrating From HSQL DB 2.0 to 2.3 or latest version's advantages/disadvantages

Tags: java, hsqldb

In my existing application we are using `hsqldb version:2.0.0-rc9.` I advised to figure out the impact of upgrading this hsqldb version to latest.
I did not found any useful links from any official sites.

Any link/suggestions in order to impacts on migrating/updating the current version of this db would be a great help.

```
Application Java version: 1.8
```

Comment: There's a [change list](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/changelist_2_0.txt) which lists exactly all the changes since version 2.0. It lists all the bug fixes and enhancements.

Comment: Version 2.0 is on the bottom and no list with it. It has started from 2.1.0 I guess.

Comment: The file lists all the changes since 2.0.0, which is what you are asking for - since you already have 2.0.0 now.

Answer (score 0):

The `hsqldb version:2.0.0-rc9` refers to a release candidate just before version 2.0.0. This release is quite stable.

More recent versions have many extra features, listed in the [chnagelist](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/changelist_2_0.txt) . As a result of improvements, there may be some changes in the results returned by a few complex queries. You need to check your queries against the latest version.